# Resolving promises in Protactor

Tags: promise, jasmine, protractor

I actually have issue with following code :

```
var promise = element(by.id("closeNotification")).isPresent(); // point A

console.log(promise);

promise.then((message) => {
    element(by.id("closeNotification")).click();
        browser.sleep(3000);
}, (errorMessage) => {                // Point B
    browser.refresh();
});
```

Here at point A, if element is present, program runs smoothly. But if element is not present, an error is thrown. At point B i have tried to handle the promise if it is rejected. Please help me with the condition if element is not present.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protractor waiting for element to be in DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30205235/protractor-waiting-for-element-to-be-in-dom)

Comment: And/or [Creating and resolving promises in protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24289431/creating-and-resolving-promises-in-protractor)

Comment: My issue is that element may or may not appear on every test run. Both suggested questions do not address this issue @Gunderson

Answer (score 0):

move the click into `if` block, only when element is present, then execute click

```
var promise = element(by.id("closeNotification")).isPresent(); // point A

promise.then((present) => {
    if(present) { // only click when present == true
        element(by.id("closeNotification")).click();
    }
    browser.sleep(3000);
}, (errorMessage) => {                // Point B
    browser.refresh();
});
```

Comment: It isn't working and reason is that variable 'promise' is not a boolean type but is a promise. Hence 'if' statement does not work.